# AttributeError: 'ASGIRequest' object has no attribute 'accept'

Tags: python, django, nginx, websocket, asgi

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с ошибкой.
Создал веб-приложение на django.
Подключил веб сокеты по инструкции (https://alex-oleshkevich.medium.com/websockets-in-django-3-1-73de70c5c1ba).
При запуске веб-приложения происходит подключение к веб сокетам с помощью js (ws://localhost/websocket/).
Собственно, при событии websocket.accept возникает ошибка:

```
Internal Server Error: /websocket/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/microwire/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 458, in thread_handler
    raise exc_info[1]
  File "/home/pi/microwire/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 38, in inner
    response = await get_response(request)
  File "/home/pi/microwire/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 233, in _get_response_async
    response = await wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "./app/views.py", line 76, in websocket
    await socket.accept()
AttributeError: 'ASGIRequest' object has no attribute 'accept'
```

Список зависимостей:

```
asgiref             3.3.4   
click               7.1.2   
Django              3.2.3   
django-user-agents  0.4.0   
djangorestframework 3.12.4  
gunicorn            20.1.0  
h11                 0.12.0  
pip                 18.1    
pkg-resources       0.0.0   
psycopg2            2.8.6   
pytz                2021.1  
setuptools          40.8.0  
sqlparse            0.4.1   
typing-extensions   3.10.0.0
ua-parser           0.10.0  
user-agents         2.2.0   
uvicorn             0.13.4
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import *
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Settings
from microwire.connection import WebSocket

async def websocket(socket: WebSocket):
    await socket.accept()
    while True:
        message = await socket.receive_text()
        await socket.send_text(message)

def index(request):
    current_settings = Settings.objects.all()[0]
    settings = Settings.objects.all()[1:]
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'current_settings': current_settings, 'settings': settings})
```

urls.py:

```
from app import views
from django.urls import path, include

websocket = path

urlpatterns = [
    websocket('websocket/', views.websocket),
    path('', views.index)
]
```

asgi.py:

```
import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from .middleware import websockets

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'microwire.settings')

application = get_asgi_application()
application = websockets(application)
```

Comment: Покажите views.py и urls.py

Comment: @andreymal добавил в вопрос

Comment: @andreymal, во-первых, есть, а во-вторых, это никак не влияет на ошибку.

Comment: middleware подключить не забыли? Покажите asgi.py

Comment: @andreymal добавил в вопрос. Но скорее всего дело в чем-то другом, поскольку запускаю на стационарном ПК под Windows - всё работает как надо, переношу всё на Raspberry Pi под Raspbian и запускаю там - ошибка.

Comment: А, ну если на ПК работает, тогда дело видимо действительно не в коде. А какой именно командой вы запускаете на Pi?

Comment: @andreymal uvicorn microwire.asgi:application. На стационарном ПК запускаю той же командой. Но на Pi uvicorn работает вместе с nginx.  Может быть дело в настройке Nginx? Развертывание делал по инструкции (https://evileg.com/ru/post/3/). Только вместо gunicorn использовал uvicorn.

Comment: А, ну так-то да, в настройках nginx тоже нужно включить поддержку websocket

Comment: @andreymal как это сделать? необходимо правильно сконфигурировать файл /etc/nginx/sites-available/default? Буду благодарен, если подскажешь что нужно туда добавить, поскольку я ни разу с этим не сталкивался

Comment: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/websocket.html